# HTML table <td> linked to Javascript how?

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

I have an order form within an HTML table associated to some JavaScript verification logic. The current code works but I would like some enhancements to be implemented.

Currently, pressing the "verify" order button gives me the following output:

> Line 0 = 1 Qty Line 1 = 4 Qty Line 2 = 2 Qty

Instead of showing table lines numbers followed by quantity value, I need the text to contain the actual products names. E.g. "*Line 0 = 1*" → "*Apple = 1*" …

I cannot really seem to figure it out can someone tell me how to do this?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" TYPE="text/javascript">
    <!-- Original:  Mike McGrath   (mike_mcgrath@example.net) -->
    <!-- Web Site:  http://website.example.net/~mike_mcgrath/ -->
    <!--

    function count(f, n, u) {
      f.line_sum[n].value = f.line[n].value * u;
      f.line_sum[n].value = Math.ceil(f.line_sum[n].value * 1000) / 1000;
      f.line_sum[n].value = Math.floor(f.line_sum[n].value * 1000) / 1000;
      f.line_sum[n].value = Math.round(f.line_sum[n].value * 100) / 100;
      if (f.line_sum[n].value == "NaN") {
        alert("Error:\nYou may only enter numbers...\nPlease retry");
        f.line[n].value = f.line[n].value.substring(0, f.line[n].value.length - 1);
        f.line_sum[n].value = f.line[n].value * u;
        if (f.line_sum[n].value == "0") f.line_sum[n].value = "";
      } else {
        var gt = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < f.line_sum.length; i++) {
          gt += Math.ceil(f.line_sum[i].value * 1000) / 1000;
        }
        gt = Math.round(gt * 1000) / 1000;
        f.grand_total.value = "$ " + gt;
        decimal(f);
      }
    }

    function get_data(f) {
      var order_data = "This Order is ...\n";
      for (i = 0; i < f.line.length; i++) {
        if (f.line[i].value == "") f.line[i].value = "0";
        order_data += "Line " + i + " = " + f.line[i].value + " Qty\n";
      }
      if (f.grand_total.value == "") f.grand_total.value = "Nil";
      order_data += "Total Order Value = " + f.grand_total.value;
      document.g.order.value = order_data;
    }

    function decimal(f) {
      for (i = 0; i < f.line_sum.length; i++) {
        var d = f.line_sum[i].value.indexOf(".");
        if (d == -1 && f.line[i].value != 0) f.line_sum[i].value += ".00";
        if (d == (f.line_sum[i].value.length - 2)) f.line_sum[i].value += "0";
        if (f.line_sum[i].value == "00") f.line_sum[i].value = "";
      }
      d = f.grand_total.value.indexOf(".");
      if (d == -1) f.grand_total.value += ".00";
      if (d == (f.grand_total.value.length - 2)) f.grand_total.value += "0";
    }

    function send_data(g) {
      get_data(document.f);
      if (document.f.grand_total.value == "Nil") {
        var conf = confirm("No items are entered - \nDo you want to submit a blank order?");
        if (conf) g.submit();
        else init();
      } else g.submit();
    }

    function init() {
      document.f.reset();
      document.f.line[0].select();
      document.f.line[0].focus();
      document.g.order.value = "";
    }

    window.onload = init;

    // -->
  </SCRIPT>


</head>

<body>

  <FORM NAME="f">
    <TABLE BGCOLOR="mistyrose" BORDER="2" WIDTH="320" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" SUMMARY="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">
            <B>Order Form</B>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR BGCOLOR="beige">
          <TD>
            <U>Item</U>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <U>Qty</U>
          </TD>
          <TD>
            <U>Each</U>
          </TD>
          <TD ALIGN="right">
            <U>Total</U>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>Apple</TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT NAME="line" TYPE="text" SIZE="5" VALUE="" ONKEYUP="count(this.form,0,5.95)">
          </TD>
          <TD>$ 5.95</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="right">
            <INPUT NAME="line_sum" TYPE="text" SIZE="10" READONLY>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR BGCOLOR="beige">
          <TD>Banana</TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT NAME="line" TYPE="text" SIZE="5" VALUE="" ONKEYUP="count(this.form,1,10.95)">
          </TD>
          <TD>$ 10.95</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="right">
            <INPUT NAME="line_sum" TYPE="text" SIZE="10" READONLY>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD>Orange</TD>
          <TD>
            <INPUT NAME="line" TYPE="text" SIZE="5" VALUE="" ONKEYUP="count(this.form,2,20.95)">
          </TD>
          <TD>$ 20.95</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="right">
            <INPUT NAME="line_sum" TYPE="text" SIZE="10" READONLY>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR BGCOLOR="beige">
          <TD>
            <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Reset" ONCLICK="init()">
          </TD>
          <TD COLSPAN="2" ALIGN="right">
            <U>Grand Total :</U>
          </TD>
          <TD ALIGN="right">
            <INPUT NAME="grand_total" TYPE="text" SIZE="10" READONLY>
          </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD COLSPAN="4" ALIGN="center">
            <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Press to Verify Order" ONCLICK="get_data(this.form)">
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TBODY>
    </TABLE>
  </FORM>
  <FORM NAME="g" METHOD="post" ENCTYPE="text/plain" ACTION="mailto:user@isp">
    <TABLE BGCOLOR="cadetblue" BORDER="4" WIDTH="320" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0" SUMMARY="">
      <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD ALIGN="center">
            <TEXTAREA NAME="order" ROWS="5" COLS="35">
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: yes but does jQuery work together with the javascript code i'm using right now?

Comment: @WietskeKoelma jQuery is JavaScript, it's a library. So yes.

Comment: oke! but can any one help with this? i tried somethings but my javascript knowledge is not that good.